# Expand DIV outside the width of its parent

Tags: html, css

I have a grid and each square opens a new DIV on-mouse-over.

[image]

I want to align the popup div to the big parent DIV, like this:

[image]

The small squares are LIs, here's the code:

```
<div class="esg-overflowtrick" style="width: 100%; height: 450px; overflow: hidden;">

<ul class="mainul" style="height: 450px;">

<li id="eg-1-post-id-264_9785" class="filterall eg-cleveland-wrapper tp-esg-item itemtoshow isvisiblenow" style="opacity: 1; visibility: inherit; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0.1px); padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; height: 150px; width: 150px; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px; z-index: 5;">

<div class="esg-media-cover-wrapper">
<div class="esg-entry-media-wrapper esg-entry-media-wrapper-even">
<div class="esg-entry-media" style="padding-bottom: 100%;">
<div class="esg-media-poster" style="opacity: 1; visibility: inherit; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="esg-overlay esg-transition eg-cleveland-container" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; transform-style: flat; transform: translate(0px);"></div>
<div class="esg-entry-content" style="min-height: 0px; display: none;">
<p>content</p>
</div>
</div>

</li>
</ul></div>
```

**esg-entry-content**'s width is limited by the width of the LI. How can I bypass that and expand its width to the UL's width?

I tried giving it a width in pixels, but it goes out of bounds, it doesn't stay inside the UL's width.

Comment: set `position :absolute !important;` then you can put the desired width to the div

Comment: @Mr.Fontastic Good question, but could you share your CSS stylesheet referenced by this markup or remove these classes if they're irrelevant? Thanks.

Comment: AbdelraoufFerah, it didn't work.
@ggorlen You are right, I will update the question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Fontastic i think u will update,we are too eager to answer this question

Comment: My question is - is it necessary to keep div inside od li? If yes, do you know exactly size the size of parent eleent and position of div?